# nodejs lstat does not find the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, file

I am listing files recursively but I get the following error when I try to list all the files from a sub directory.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'config'
    at Object.lstatSync (fs.js:838:3)
    at files.forEach.file (D:\merkletrool\dataAccess.js:13:32)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at fs.readdir (D:\merkletrool\dataAccess.js:12:15)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

The code is the following:

```
function listAllFiles(path) {
    console.log("directory path " + path);
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
                console.log(err);
        }
        files.forEach(file => {
            let file_stat = fs.lstatSync(file);
            if (file_stat.isFile()) {
                list_files.push(file);
                console.log("is file");
            } else if (file_stat.isDirectory()) {
                console.log(file + " here");
                listAllFiles(path + file + "\\");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

At first I thought the path was incorrect, which was, so I added the

```
path + file + "\\"
```

But the problem is not that. The error SEEMS to be related with the file called "config" in the .git folder. For a reason I don't understand, it says it does not exists, but it does. Any tip to help me understand and fix?

Full console log:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first instinct was indeed correct. The error plainly shows you are trying to read the file `config` from the current working directory, not the `.git` directory.

Make sure you are prefixing your files with the path, like so:

```
files.forEach(file => {
    let file_stat = fs.lstatSync(require('path').join(path, file));
```

(Note: typically you'd `const path = require('path');` at top of your file. I recommend that, but then make sure to rename your function argument `path` - `filePath` is a good substitute.)